# reload/refresh the dataTable

Tags: datatables

I want to reload/refresh the data in dataTable after I click on refresh button.
Currently I am calling the dataTable intialisation function on button click but that's sending the ajax request again and again.
Is there any other way to reload/refresh the dataTable?

Comment: You have to rebind to your datalayer. Mind posting some code?

Comment: I didn't get you Damien.

Comment: Can you post some code that you tried so I can help you better?

Comment: For now I am sending ajax request again on a button click event (reinitializing the dataTable) and what I want is just refresh the dataTable with reinitializing.
    oTable = $("#jsDataTable").dataTable({});
This is what I am doing on button click.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yourTable.fnDraw();` or `fnReloadAjax` depending on your requirement. Read about it [here](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api)

Answer (score 0):

If its server-side , set bDestroy=true ( http://datatables.net/usage/options)

Typically i set my datadbles function to a variable oTable, then on subsequent click functions call oTable.fnDraw(); found it works better than fnReload ajax when different params are passed

Answer (score 0):

I have used oTable.fnDraw() method to refresh my datatable after deletion or active/deactive  some event.
Where oTable is the object of Your Table.